# To get accustomed to something. How to use "sich gewöhnen"

Tags: preposition, verb-usage, reflexive

How do you express "to be used to something" when the object is a phrase. For example "I am accustomed to drinking coffee every morning." Can the direct object of "sich gewöhnen" be a stand-alone Nebensatz or does it have to be referred to with the preposition "an" as below?

Which is correct?

"Ich gewöhne mich daran, Kaffe jeden Morgen zu trinken." OR
"Ich gewöhne mich, Kaffe jeden Morgen zu trinken."

Answer (score 2):

- I am accustomed to drinking coffee every morning.

This is usually phrased as:

> Ich bin **daran** gewöhnt, jeden Morgen Kaffee zu trinken.

That *daran* is the crucial part. The verb phrase is *an etwas gewöhnt sein — to be accustomed to something* and it has that prepositional object *an etwas*. If you want to use a clause instead of a noun phrase, you have to retain the preposition. That's the purpose of the *da*-adverb *daran*. It has that *an* built in so the verb phrase of the main clause is complete.

---

Note that there is another way to phrase this:

> Ich bin es gewöhnt, jeden Morgen Kaffee zu trinken.

This is a different verb phrase *gewöhnt sein* without a prepositional object. It uses a plain accusative object instead. If you want to use a clause instead of an accusative object, you often need an *es* in the main clause.

Comment: The question refers to the reflexive verb "sich gewöhnen" - "to get used to/to adapt to". You're talking about the adjective with "sien", "gewohnt sein" - "fo be used to/adapted to". It's a different phrasing, and I'm not sure that it means exactly the same thing. In any case, my DWDS search turned up many examples of the reflexive version, e.g. "Sie werden sich dran gewöhnen." so I think it deserves some discussion even if it's not the most common phrasing.

Comment: It doesn't mean the same thing. The phrase *I'm accustomed to* cannot be translated with *gewöhnen* and neither *sich gewöhnen*. Those call for *to accustom someone/yourself to*. You have to use the Zustandspassiv *gewöhnt sein* or the alternative *gewohnt sein*.

Comment: The adjective is actually **gewohnt**. **Gewöhnt** is the past participle of the verb *gewöhnen*.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that German doesn't have a direct (or indirect) object.

Your sentence "Ich gewöhne mich daran, Kaffee jeden Morgen zu trinken." sounds better than "Ich gewöhne mich, Kaffee jeden Morgen zu trinken." but I wouldn't call the second sentence wrong. But it doesn't express the state of being used to something, it expresses the process of getting used to something.

If you are already used to something, you can say "Ich bin es gewohnt, Kaffee jeden Morgen zu trinken."

Also, the word order "Kaffee jeden Morgen zu trinken" is slightly unusual and puts the emphasis on the coffee. You could use it to say that you drink coffee, not tea. Otherwise I would use "jeden Morgen Kaffee zu trinken"

In German, "Kaffee" is written with two "f" and two "e", as is coffee in English.